# iOS Sharing Extension/Widget On iPhone and Ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am trying to write a today widget which will have the same user interface for both iPhone and iPad but I don't want to create the same widget's target twice for both project. How would I go about to share the widget on both iPhone and iPad project?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special. Your today widget is available when you install the app on iPhone or iPad. Be aware that on iPad the screen is wider, so you could use the extra space by resizing your widget (e.g. by using auto layout).